# Why I can't use tag of <spring:message?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

Using in my jsp like:
 `<spring:message code="key1"/>` ,
I got error:
  ** `Root cause is: No message found under code 'key1' for locale 'zh_CN'. javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: No message found under code 'key1' for locale 'zh_CN'. at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.MessageTag.doStartTagInternal(MessageTag.java:184) at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:79) at`

And the following is my code:

```
<bean id="messageSource"        class="org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basename" value="com.bk.message.Message" />
        <property name="defaultEncoding" value="UTF-8" />
        <property name="useCodeAsDefaultMessage" value="false" />
    </bean>
```

here is my properties:

```
Message_zh_CN.properties under folder src/com/bk/message  
key1=This
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey, `basename` should be a path, not a package name.  See the documentation [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/1.2.9/api/org/springframework/context/support/ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.html#setBasename%28java.lang.String%29) and some discussion [here](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-11883.html).

If you want to debug, btw, just inject the bean somewhere in your code.

Comment: Thanks. I put Message_zh_CN.properties under WEB-INF/messages and change config to <property name="basename" value="WEB-INF/messages/Message" />, it works. But How to specify multiple message property files?

Comment: I got the answer:<property name="basenames">
  <list>
  <value>WEB-INF/messages/task</value>
  <value>WEB-INF/messages/common</value>
  <value>WEB-INF/messages/user</value>
  </list>
  </property>

Answer (score 1):

Hey,it is more useful to put the configuration in applicationContext.xml. And then you can load the properties from classpath,such as

```
 <bean id="messageSource"
   class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
        <property name="basenames">
            <list>
            <value>i18n/views</value>
                   </list>      
            </property>     
    </bean>
```

Now, you can load many properties which are defined by youself.